# how to generate only one special character in this password generator

Tags: shell-script

I have a command which generates password with multiple special characters. How can I make it to generate only 1 special character?

```
# Generate a random password
#  $1 = number of characters; defaults to 32
#  $2 = include special characters; 1 = yes, 0 = no; defaults to 1
function randpass() {
  [ "$2" == "0" ] && CHAR="[:alnum:]" || CHAR="[:graph:]"
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "$CHAR" | head -c ${1:-32}
    echo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would generate 32 `[:alnum:]` characters first, and then optionally insert a special character:

```
function randpass() {
  passwd=$( < /dev/urandom tr -cd "[:alnum:]" | head -c $1)
  if [ "$2" == "0" ]; then
    echo "$passwd"
  else
    spchar=$( < /dev/urandom tr -cd "[:punct:]" | head -c 1)
    pos=$((RANDOM%$1))
    echo "${passwd:0:pos}${spchar}${passwd:pos+1:$1}"
  fi
}
```

I assume the `[:punct:]` contains all the characters you consider "special".

The `$(( ))` syntax is a [shell arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) which generates a random number between 0 and 31 (or whatever `$1` is).

The `${var:offset:length}` syntax is a [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to return a substring from a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of approaches:

#### 1. Iterate until you get a password that you “like”

```
while true
do
    word=$(tr -cd "[:graph:]" < /dev/urandom | head -c ${1:-32})
    if [[ "$word" =~ [[:punct:]].*[[:punct:]] ]]
    then
        echo "$word has multiple special characters - reject."
        continue
    fi
    if [[ "$word" =~ [[:punct:]] ]]
    then
        echo "$word has one special character - accept."
        break
    fi
    echo "$word has no special characters - reject."
    continue
done
```

Warning: this may take a long time for a large number of characters (e.g., > 16).

#### 2. Stop after you get one punctuation character

```
n=${1:-32}
if [ "$2" == "0" ]
then
    CHAR="[:alnum:]"
else
    CHAR="[:graph:]"
fi
word=
for ((i=0; i<n; i++))
do
    thischar=$(tr -cd "$CHAR" < /dev/urandom | head -c 1)
    if ! [[ "$thischar" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]]
                            # Probably equivalent to if [[ "$thischar" =~ [[:punct:]] ]]
    then
        # Got one special character – don’t allow any more.
        echo "$thischar is a special character."
        CHAR="[:alnum:]"
    fi
    word="$word$thischar"
done
echo "$word"
```

Note that this gets the special char in the first three
(e.g., `ab!defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456`) *very* often. 
Also, it is theoretically possible to get a password with no special characters
using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `head` command to `-c 1`:

```
# Generate a random password
#  $1 = number of characters; defaults to 32
#  $2 = include special characters; 1 = yes, 0 = no; defaults to 1
function randpass() {
  [ "$2" == "0" ] && CHAR="[:alnum:]" || CHAR="[:graph:]"
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "$CHAR" | head -c 1
    echo
}
```

Comment: No what i meant was to have only 1 special character inside the password like Gj69*nvJ3

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case, please [edit] your question and explain what you call "special" characters.