# generate password that is random length between 8 - 16 ( i have the generator but its not dynamic)

Tags: bash

This is my password generator and it generates 8 characters and shuffles them. But i need to make it dynamic length. How would i go about doing that. So the output would be different length between 8 - 16 characters.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
num=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" "8" "9")
special=("@" "#" "$" "%" "*" "-" "+")
upper=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
lower=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
lower2=${#lower[*]}   #${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}
upper2=${#upper[*]}   #${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}
num2=${#num[*]}     #${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}
special2=${#special[*]} #${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}

echo "${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d '\n'
echo
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
len=$((8+RANDOM%9))
```

and then generate `$len` characters, using a framework like the one I offered in my answer to your very closely related [how to generate only one special character in this password generator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156491/80216) question,

```
word=
for ((i=0; i<len; i++))
do
    thischar=(Generate one character by whatever logic you like)
    word="$word$thischar"
done
echo "$word"
```

I leave it to you to decide how to generate the individual characters
so you get a character group distribution to your liking. 
That's beyond the scope of your question, and would get into writing your requirements
(i.e., writing *your question*) for you.